# Disable automatic "mark as read" in thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I would like to mark as read my email manually, I do not want thunderbird to mark as read automatically, which would make me forget about email to reply to.

I have Thunderbird 52.2.1 (64 bits) on Ubuntu 17.04. In previous versions, I went to "edit>preferences>advanced" and I found the option to disable this thing. But in this version, it disappeared.

Where can I find it?

EDIT:
I upgraded to Thunderbird 52.3 and, as you can see from the picture, the situation does not change

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's now under (*Edit* >) *Preferences* > *Display* > *Advanced*, at least in 52.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. Everyone was suggesting to

```
(Edit >) Preferences > Display > Advanced
```

but ... there are two "Advanced" buttons, as you can see in the picture. one on the right and one on the top (that does not even seem a button). Well, you have to press the one at the top (whereas I was clicking the other)...

If any thunderbird developers are around: guys, what are these jokes? Please, make sure buttons appear as buttons and avoid to place two buttons with the same name in the same menu, it is very confusing, particularly when trying to follow instructions from others

Answer (score 1):

So that is big joke. I was also frustrating. 
The problem is that this apears even now after 2 years !!!.

The another possiility how to stop or change it is to edit the settings directly. It is the item:
mailnews.mark_message_read.auto;false

and set it to false.